# How Can I use Chromium or Webkit source code in our custom browser?

Tags: browser, twebbrowser

I am trying to develop my own browser by using chromium source code but am not familiar with browser part.please give some valuable suggestions how to start from scratch using "Chromium Source code"....

Answer (score 0):

There are two very high quality Chromium wrapper projects for Delphi.

- https://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/
- https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/

Note that both projects seem not to be very active since 2014.

*If you think the answer is helpful to you, please accept the answer.*